# Apache 301 RewriteRule not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a variety of redirects, mostly more complex, that are working in this format.  This simple redirect, however, is not.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=461$ [NC]
RewriteRule page.asp http://www.website.com/legal-notices [R=301,L]

I've tried redirect 301 and other things, but its not working

I'm attempting to get /page.asp?id=461 to redirect to /legal-notices/

Any help?  Thanks